# How to access parent tableview indexpath.section in child tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Main Tableview in that cell I have a collectionview and in that cell, I have a tableview, I want to access parent tableviewcell in my sub tableview, when user selects a perticular child table i want to access the main tableview indexpath of section.

Now in code I am taking a global `Int` variable and taking the main section `indexPath` and trying to access that index but I am getting wrong results:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let list:[String:Any] = arrOfObjs1[indexPath.row]
    
    // This is global integer Variable 
    Utilities.shared().sectionInEntityInstance = indexPath.section

    let typeStr:String = list["type"] as! String
    
    if typeStr == "column" {
        let list1:[Any] = list["list"] as! [Any]
        let item:[String:Any] = list1[indexPath.row] as! [String : Any]
        
        let info:[String:Any] = item["info"] as! [String : Any]
        
        let dataTypeId:Int = info["dataTypeId"] as! Int
        if dataTypeId == 4 {
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EntityInstanceTextCell")
            cell?.textLabel?.text = info["label"] as? String
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(item["value"] ?? "")"
            return cell!
        }
        
    } else if typeStr == "section" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EntityInstanceTableViewCell") as! EntityInstanceTableViewCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.section
        print("cellTag:>>> \(cell.tag)")
        var listOfColumns:[Any] = []
        if list["list"] != nil {
            listOfColumns.append(contentsOf: list["list"] as! [Any])
        }
        
        let list1 = entitiesList
        let listObj:[[String:Any]] = list1[indexPath.section] as! [[String:Any]]
        cell.loadTabs(tabs: listObj, index: cell.tag)
        Utilities.shared().tabsDataArray.removeAll()
        Utilities.shared().tabsDataArray.append(contentsOf: listOfColumns)
      
        return cell
    } else if typeStr == "field" {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomLabelTableViewCell") as! CustomLabelTableViewCell
        let list1 = entitiesList
        
        let listObj:[[String:Any]] = list1[indexPath.section] as! [[String:Any]]
        
        let predicateData = NSPredicate(format: "paramId = %@", (list["paramId"] as? String)!)
        
        let filteredArray:[Any] = (listObj.filter { predicateData.evaluate(with: $0) });
        print(filteredArray)
        let filteredObj:[String:Any] = filteredArray.first as! [String : Any]
        let info:[String:Any] = filteredObj["info"] as! [String:Any]
        //let str = info["label"] as! String
        cell.titleLbl.text = info["label"] as? String
        // cell.titleLbl.text = "\(str):"
        cell.detailedLbl.text = (filteredObj["value"] as! String)
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it s correct design, but you can use delegate mechanism or use notification kind a https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus

Comment: Sorry, but your code is not supposed to work at all. Storing the `indexPath` into a global variable will not help at all, because the function `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` will be called all the time a cell is to be displayed. This is completele independend from any selection, tapping etc.
I would suggest to completly rething the data structures. Also, if I got it right, you are nesting table views inside table views, which also could be very confusing to the user and does not look like a good UI design to me.

Comment: The design is that i supposed to set a columns so i nested tableview inside table their is a collection and inside collection their is a table if their are any number of columns then thouse columns will be displayed by using collectionview with subview as tableview, and my problem is that when user selects inner table then i cant get the parent table indexPath of section , how can i archive that ? can you suggest me any solution . Thanks for your reply .